# How to import a remote resource while performing an apply in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm using Terraform to create some resources. One of the side effects of creating the resource is the creation of another resource (let's call this B). The issue is that I can't access B to edit it in terraform because terraform considers it as "out of the state". I can't also import B in the state before the `terraform apply` is started because B does not exist.

Is there any solution to add (import) a remote resource to the state while running the `apply` command?

I'm thinking about this as a general question, if there was no solution I can also share the details of the resources I'm creating.

More details:
When I create a "Storage Account" on Azure using Terraform and enable static_website, Azure automatically creates a `storage_container` named `$web`. I need to edit one of the attributes of the `$web` container but Terraform tells me it is not in the current state and needs to be imported. Storage Account is A, Container is B

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding why `apply` does not create `B` for you, as a dependency of `A`. Can you share more details?

Comment: @MohammadJafarMashhadi I added some details.

Comment: Haven't worked with Azure before, but if it's similar to AWS you might be able to create the storage container yourself so that you can have it in the state and customize it

Comment: `resource "azurerm_storage_container" xxx { storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.xxx.name}`

Comment: This module might help as well: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/avinor/storage-account/azurerm/latest

Comment: These are steps I took initially and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have an answer to your specific question of importing a resource during an apply. The fundamental premise of Terraform is that it manages resources from creation. Therefore, you need to have a (in this case, `azurerm_storage_container`) resource declared, before you can import the current state of that resource into your state.

In an ideal world you would be able to explicitly create the container first and specify that the storage account uses that, but a quick look in the docs does not suggest that is an option (and I think is something you have already tried). If it is not exposed in Terraform, that is likely because it is not exposed by the Azure API (Disclaimer: not an Azure user)

The only (bad) answer I can think to suggest, is that you define an [`azurerm_storage_container`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/storage_container) *data* resource in your code, dependent on the the `azurerm_storage_account` resource, that will be able to pull back the details of the created container. You could then potentially have a [`null_resource`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource) that calls a [`local-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) provisioner that can fire a CLI command, using the params taken from the data resource to allow you to use the Azure CLI tools to edit the container.

I really hope someone else can come along with a better answer tho :|